# How do I select from xml document multiple times with powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to select multiple groups of elements from an XML document, the sample below shows the type of structure I'm using. Why does the powershell code below only output the 2 names, but not the 2 stores.

```
[xml]$xml = @'
<root>
  <node>
    <store>HEB</store>
    <name>Fred</name>
  </node>
  <node>
    <store>Fred Meyer</store>
    <name>Barney</name>
  </node>
</root>
'@;

$xml.root.node | select  name -unique

$xml.root.node | select store -unique
```

Output

```
.\test.ps1

name
----
Fred
Barney
```

Desired Output

```
.\test.ps1

name
----
Fred
Barney

store
-----
HEB
Fred Meyer
```

Comment: Where is message defined in the XML? I don't see it.

Comment: can you post your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
[xml]$xml = @'
<root>
  <node>
    <store>HEB</store>
    <name>Fred</name>
  </node>
  <node>
    <store>Fred Meyer</store>
    <name>Barney</name>
  </node>
</root>
'@;

$xml.root.node | select name  -unique | Out-String

$xml.root.node | select store -unique | Out-String
```

The issue appears to be only when you run the code from a script (.ps1). When you run the raw code from the prompt, it works perfectly.

The issue that you are encountering is how PowerShell returns the output from a script. Whenever possible it will try to return the full object rather than finally defaulting to a base string object.

So lets step through this:

Original code:

```
$xml.root.node | select  name -unique
$xml.root.node | select store -unique

PS C:\> $a = .\Test.ps1
PS C:\> $a

name
----
Fred
Barney



PS C:\> $a | Get-Member


   TypeName: Selected.System.Xml.XmlElement

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
name        NoteProperty System.String name=Fred
```

Notice that the TypeName is a XmlElement, and based on the members, there is a NoteProperty "name".

When we flip the code around:

```
$xml.root.node | select store -unique
$xml.root.node | select  name -unique

PS C:\> $b = .\Test.ps1
PS C:\> $b

store
-----
HEB
Fred Meyer




PS C:\> $b | Get-Member


   TypeName: Selected.System.Xml.XmlElement

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
store       NoteProperty System.String store=HEB
```

Notice that the TypeName is a XmlElement, and there is a NoteProperty "store".

Basically what is happening is that once PowerShell hits the first command it sets the "Output" variable type to the first element, i.e. name. When it hits the second element, it tries to shove the contents into the predefined output type, and fills it with nothing (because there is no name field). You can verify this by getting the count:

```
PS C:\> $a.Count
4
```

So there are 4 elements, but only the first two actually contain information that we want.

The workaround is to output both elements as a string so that the Output type is a string, then it will return both values.

```
PS C:\> $c = .\Test.ps1
PS C:\> $c

name
----
Fred
Barney




store
-----
HEB
Fred Meyer
```

Comment: Agreed, it was a typo from the original script, however even when corrected the script only outputs the name information, not the store info.

Comment: Ah. Well that was an interesting problem, it runs fine in the prompt, but not in a .ps1 file. I figured out what was going on and edited my answer.